# AppCenter support for Genie

Tags: language

I know that we can develop application in Vala for elemantry. But, do we have support for Genie? If I write application in Genie, should it has elemantry support?

Answer (score 1):

Support for Genie is built into the Vala compiler.  You can install the Vala compiler as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install valac
```

From this you may compile either Vala or Genie, as, for example:

```
$ valac example.gs -o example
```

Then run as:

```
$ ./example
```

You can also compile both Vala and Genie as, for example:

```
$ valac example.vala example.gs -o example
```

If you are feeling more intrepid, [Gnome-Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder) is an IDE that can be used to build projects for both Vala and Genie using the Meson build system.

Stackoverflow has a tag for Genie; it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genie).

The best documentation on the internet may be found at the Elementary OS [Developer Center](https://developer.elementary.io).

Comment: Thanks, but I think you have not read my question carefully. I have asked for eOS's AppCenter support for Genie not how to install or compile program genie program .

Comment: @Kiran _Gnome Builder_ is the go to IDE for Vala (Gnome) that also supports Genie (because it uses the Vala compiler) and can be installed from the AppCenter.  Also the default EOS text editor _Scratch_ (installed by default) _Glade_ and the _ValaCompiler_ gui can be used for Genie development.  Otherwise I am not aware of any other Genie programming language packages in the AppCenter.

Comment: @Kiran When it comes to Genie development, I prefer to use https://www.flatpak.org/ to get Vala/Genie nightly-build development tools because they are more up to date and contain a more features.  This is my preferred way to install _Gnome Builder_ and _Glade_ as well as many other Gnome apps.  Once installed, you can invoke them the first time from the terminal prompt as `flatpak run org.gnome.<Program>` and then right click their icon to 'Keep in Dock' for future access.